# What process could be grabbing alt-tab?

Tags: shortcut-keys, kde, workspaces, window-management

I'm running KDE on Focal and had to reboot a few days ago. The normal thing for alt-tab to do is show a list of the windows on this workspace on the left side of the screen and cycle through them. Now, however, it shows all the windows on all the workspaces in the middle of them and cycles through them. This is annoying; if I'm on workspace 2, where I have all windows relating to a program I'm working on, I want to cycle through only those windows, not my email or YouTube or anything else.

In System Settings|Window Management|Task Switcher, there's a Main tab where I can click on a button and change the key for cycling forward through windows to, say, ctrl-alt-tab (which normally cycles through tabs in one window). If I do that, ctrl-alt-tab cycles through the windows on this workspace, showing them on the left, while alt-tab cycles through all windows, showing them in the center. That tells me that something is grabbing alt-tab before KWin gets it. How do I find out what grabs it?

Comment: This is KDE? Would be good to also mention that in the beginning of your question. Otherwise, people will be inclined to think this is about the default Ubuntu desktop using Gnome Shell.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't found out how to find what process is grabbing a keystroke, but I found out what process was grabbing alt-tab. It is `ukui-window-switch`, which I never heard of before. I found a core file of this program in my home directory. Suspecting that it had something to do with alt-tab, I hit alt-tab; konsole acted as if I had just typed tab. I then ran `ukui-window-switch`, and all the windows in all the workspaces showed up in the middle of the screen when I hit alt-tab. I killed `ukui-window-switch`, and alt-tab went back to being just tab. I set alt-tab in Task Switcher and now it works normally.